# One login for multiple products

Tags: python, django, authorization, server-side

There are multiple mobile apps.
I want people using one app to login with their same login credentials into all other apps.

What is the best approach to implement this?

I'm thinking to create a separate authorization server that will issue tokens/secrets on registering and logins. It will have a validation API that will be used by mobile app servers to validate requests.

Comment: IMHO you should have a look at single sign-on patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First check if `OAuth` could be adapted to using this, that would save you a lot of work. Of course all the services and apps would have to talk to some backend network server to sync tokens issued to apps.
2. Half-secure/maybe-abusable solution: have symmetric cipher encrypted cookie that webpages (and apps?) hold and use it for authorization with different network services (which again have to verify cookie for authorization with authorization service that knows the passphrase used to encrypt the cookie)

I've used approach #2 on internal systems but I am not sure if it is advisable to use it in in the wild - this may pose some security risks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a protocol for handling this called Central Authentication Service(http://www.jasig.org/cas), or CAS. CAS utilizes OAuth2 protocol to provide a secure way to manage a single sign on procedure -- users have a single login credential that is used via tokens and proxy tickets to authenticate the user across a variety of applications using a single CAS authentication server. This is a procedure the company I work for uses to authenticate users across multiple applications (we use Java with Spring Security and Spring CAS) however this summer we built out a proof of concept with Django and an internal company API in which we implemented CAS procedure with the Django application -- Django authenticated users via the CAS server we run and returned them as valid, authenticated Django users. To do this we used the django-cas middleware and custom backend library which can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/cpcc/django-cas/overview.

CAS is definitely the way to go if you're looking to handle user authentication with a single sign on across multiple applications -- it was the reason CAS was created in the first place. The learning curve with CAS can be a little steep but django-cas does a good enough job making it easy to get set up with CAS in the Django project.

Answer (score 0):

The authentification method in every application connects to the same webservice for autentification.